# Set focus on next textbox/tabindex after autopostback ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that this question was already asked a lot of times, but every solution that I found is not solving my problem.

In my page, I am creating multiple GridViews with 3 columns dynamically then I add them to my update panel. I populated the 3rd column with TextBox that has **TextChanged** event and **AutoPostback = true**. Now when the user pressed tab, the TextChanged event will be fired. But the focus disappears. I want it to move to the next textbox when I press tab, but it just disappears.

I tried adding `UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"` on my update panel but it didn't worked.

I also tried using this javascript:

```
var postbackElement = null;
  function SetFocusToNextControl(newTabIndex)
  {
    for (var i=0;i<=document.form1.elements.length;i++)
    {
        if (document.form1.elements[i].tabIndex == newTabIndex)
        {
          document.form1.elements[i].focus();
          break;
        }
    }
  }
  function RestoreFocus(source, args)
  {
    document.getElementById(postbackElement.id).focus();
    if (document.getElementById(postbackElement.id).type =='text')
      SetFocusToNextControl(document.getElementById(postbackElement.id).tabIndex+1)
  }
  function SavePostbackElement(source, args)
  {
    postbackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
  }
  function AddRequestHandler()
  {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(RestoreFocus);
    prm.add_beginRequest(SavePostbackElement);
  }
```

It worked when I pressed tab for the first time, TextChanged event fired, and the focus was set on the next textbox. But when I pressed tab for the second time, the focus disappears again. It only works once. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the last of textbox TextChanged event.

```
textbox2.focus();
```

Comment: this won't work because it will only focus on that specific textbox. if Textbox3 fired the TextChanged event, then the focus will go back to textbox2. And it will still focus on textbox2 if the user decided to click outside of textbox3 instead of pressing tab to move on the next textbox.